# VBScript Shell - Differences between Windows CMD

Tags: shell, vbscript

I'm using a Wscript.Shell object in VBScript to control a hidden shell.

I'd like to delete some test files before the app starts, so I looked into an MSDOS command to conditionally delete files.

```
if exist name del name
```

This works fine in CMD, and does not give a warning about the file not existing.
In VBScript shell however, this will generate the file not exists warning as if `if exist` wasnt part of the command.

This is especially annoying as in VBScript shell errors are displayed via MsgBox and block the app from running.

Comment: Can you show us all of your code?

Comment: @aphoria This example is very to the point. I am asking about the differences between the two shells, there's no need to show anything else.

Comment: The reason I asked is because the line of code you provided works fine. Your error was not coming from that line.

Comment: I know, please read my question again.

Comment: If you know this isn't the line generating the error, why put it in the question? You need to include the line(s) that do generate the error in your question.

Comment: But it is, my question is asking about the differences between how the two shells process that line. Albeit that's not very clear except the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(name) Then .DeleteFile name
End With
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this, but thanks for the tip on not Dimming temporary things. For the record, the difference between the shells is that Wscript's (WshShell) only looks for file or program names, not shell commands. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c348b77-18a8-4956-8561-fd97d4585cd3/diff-between-wscriptshell-and-shellapplication?forum=scripting

Answer (score 2):

`del` is an intrinsic/internal command, it's provided by the shell (cmd.exe), not by an executable named del.exe/com/.... So it 'works' from a shell/dos box/command line window.

The .Run (as the .Exec) method of the WScript.Shell object starts a process (an executable), not the shell. So `del` (and `dir`, and [other intrinsics](http://ss64.com/nt/), and I/O redirection, and 'batch language') aren't available, **unless** you start the %comspec% executable and ask that to do what you want.

So: If something like

```
if exist deleteme.tmp del deleteme.tmp
```

works from a command line window,

```
%comspec% /c if exist deleteme.tmp del deleteme.tmp
```

will work as first parameter to .Run or .Exec.

Comment: Amazing insight. Had I know this, the past 6 hours would have been more fruitful!